# "with psycopg2.connect" is it clossing connection automatically?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am using psycopg2 library to handle connection with Postgress database.

Are the following two approaches to handling db connection comparable?

Snipet 1:

```
cnx = connect(user=<...>, password=<...>, host=<...>, database=<...>)
cursor = cnx.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql)
cnx.close()
```

Snipet 2:

```
with psycopg2.connect(user=<...>, password=<...>, host=<...>, database=<...>) as cnx:
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql)
```

I am especialy interested if using WITH automatically closes connection? I was informed that second approach is preferable because it does connection close automatically. Yet when i test it using cnx.closed it shows open connection.

Comment: At what point are you using `cnx.closed` ?

Comment: ["Note that, unlike file objects or other resources, exiting the connection’s with block doesn’t close the connection but only the transaction associated with it: a connection can be used in more than a with statement and each with block is effectively wrapped in a separate transaction:"](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#with-statement)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The with block tries on exit to close (commit) a transaction, not a connection. For [the documentation:](http://psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#with-statement)

> Note that, unlike file objects or other resources, exiting the connection’s with block doesn’t close the connection but only the transaction associated with it [...]